# webview.db is empty in android 4

Tags: java, android, string, android-webview, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am creating an application based on web cache, like offline web view.
In android 2.3 I could find in webviewCache.db CACHE TABLE.

But in android 4 I cant find that  webviewCache.db or CACHE TABLE. And webview.db is also empty (another db).
I cant understand whats happening, did google but couldnt find a better answer.

if anyone knows how to find the webviewCache.db or CACHE TABLE in android 4 that will be great.
thanks...

Comment: The databases and other files maintained by `WebView` are not part of the SDK. Whatever hacks you were using may not work on any given version of Android (as you are discovering) and may not work on any given device (if the device manufacturer has tinkered with the behavior of `WebView`).

Answer (score 1):

Files such as `webviewCache.db` are part of the internal API and should not be publicly referenced by the developer. Device manufacturers (i.e. Samsung, HTC, etc.) often change parts of the internal API as they see fit, and thus, any "hacks" that you previously were using are not guaranteed to work. To ensure that your application works across ALL devices, you should only make use of the public SDK and should never reference anything internally.